# Rewriting content in Google Map InfoWidow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a simple google map with markers and infowindows (like in example at Google Maps API documentation:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
.redtext {
    color: red;
}
</style>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content"><a href="#" class="iwlink" onClick="aclick()">click me</a><P class="iwtext">Hello world!';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function aclick(){
    $(".iwtext").toggleClass("redtext");
}
</script>


  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you try this, you will see an info window after click on a marker with link (click me) and text - Hello world. If you click on a link, text become red.

But if you close infowindow, clicking on a [X], and then open it again, you will see, that text become black again, the same problem if you click again on a marker.

Is there any ways to solve this problem with rewriting content in a infowindow?

Comment: I solve it like like this: 
`function aclick(){
 $(".iwtext").toggleClass("redtext");
 contentString = '<div id="content">' + $("#content").html() + "</div>";
 infowindow.setContent(contentString);
}`
But im not shure that it is a good way to solve this problem. Maybe anyone knows how to solve this problem better?

Comment: I forgot to say, that i make contentString and infowindow variables global - but them before all functions - 
`<script>
var contentString;
var infowindow;
...
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it like like this:

```
function aclick(){ $(".iwtext").toggleClass("redtext"); contentString = '<div id="content">' + $("#content").html() + "</div>"; infowindow.setContent(contentString); }
```